# Append class to body based on which tag/href you clicked on previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, anchor

I have two pages, **"Home-Page"** and **"Landing-Page"**. I want to modify the *"Landing-Page"* content based on which button you clicked from the previous page *(That previous page being the "Home-Page")*.

I attempted to use anchor tags, but because that method relies on being client-side only, it make it difficult to work 100% of the time. Does anyone have any better options I could try in **Jquery**?

Thanks again,
Charlie

Comment: If there was a web form in where you put button?

Comment: on click of link store value to localstorage and then on the next page based on this value modify corresponding content.

Comment: That should also a good way as said by Alive.

Comment: if security is not an issue, you can add a query parameter to "landing-page", www.landingpage.com?from=button1, and read it in landing page

Answer (score 1):

The possible way - If the button in a web form then pass a value on submit and get the value form query string like `homePagebtn=TRUE` on you landing page. Another use localstorage.

Home-Page:

```
$('btn').click(function(){
localStorage.setItem("firstPagebtnValue", $(this).val());
});
```

Landing-Page:

```
var prePageValue  = localStorage.firstPagebtnValue;
if (prePageValue == 'your test value'){
  // Do you stuff with prePageValue
}  

After your code you can remove it by -

localStorage.removeItem("firstPagebtnValue");
```

Comment: This looks like the method to go. Would there need to be an if statement I'd need to write alongside the var on the Landing-Page however? How would that look like?

Comment: it should be good to ans with you actual/working code you need post you html or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: I think this will actually work mate. I'm gunna mess around with this after the client has seen the project later today. Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: Absolutely will mate!

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't require a huge safety. You can store which button was clicked in Cookie/SessionStorage.

User clicks link -> You "prevents default" -> You saves user's choose in Cookie/SessionStorage -> You "clicks" it and not preventing.

I'd recommend to check is value proper on Landing-Page(if some user would change it manually). If isn't display 404.

Comment: Cookies seem to be the default way to go. If localstorage has strong short-comings, I'll move on to cookies. Thank you!